Three tags for Multi-signature: multi-sig, multi-sig-address and multi-sig-transaction
Does it make sense to have different tags for multi-signature addresses and transactions? Aren't those intimately linked?

I just noticed that we have multi-sig, multi-sig-address, and multi-sig-transaction and was starting to write a meta post to suggest that we combine them into a single tag. Then this topic by past-Murch popped up as a potential duplicate. 
It looks like past-Murch and me agree already. Could y'all please upvote this answer if you're in support of merging the three tags? If you disagree, please downvote and add another answer with your proposal how to handle it.

Went ahead and merged the three tags, after some additional support was offered in chat.
